# looping until the number of cells changed is very small

Tags: python, while-loop

This is a repost because I'm getting weird results.  I'm trying to run a simulation loop for cells that change in a cellular automata code that changes land use codes based on their adjacent neighbors.  I import text files that create a cell id key = land use code value.  I also import a text file with each cell's adjacent neighbors.  The first time I run the code, 7509 cells changed land use based on adjacent neighbors land uses. I can comment out the reading the dictionary text file and run it again, then around 5,000 cells changed. Run it again, then even less and so on. What I would like to do is run this in a loop until only 0.0001 of the total cells change, after that break the loop.

I've tried a while loop, but it's not giving me the results I'm looking for.  After the first run, the count is correct at 7509.  After that the count is 28,476 over and over again.  I don't understand why this is happening because the count should go back to zero.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the code:

```
import sys, string, csv

#Creating a dictionary of FID: LU_Codes from external txt file
text_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\FID_Whole_Copy.txt", "rb")
#Lines = text_file.readlines()
FID_GC_dict =  dict()
reader = csv.reader(text_file, delimiter='\t')
for line in reader:
    FID_GC_dict[line[0]] = int(line[1])
text_file.close()

#Importing neighbor list file for each FID value
Neighbors_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\Pro_NL_Copy.txt","rb")
Entries = Neighbors_file.readlines()
Neighbors_file.close()

Neighbors_List = map(string.split, Entries)

#print Neighbors_List

#creates a list of the current FID
FID = [x[0] for x in Neighbors_List]

gridList = []
for nlist in Neighbors_List:
    row = []
    for item in nlist:
        row.append(FID_GC_dict[item])
    gridList.append(row)
#print gridList

#Calculate when to end of one sweep
tot_cells = len(FID)
end_sim = tot_cells
p = 0.0001
#Performs cellular automata rules on land use grid codes
while (end_sim > tot_cells*p):
    i = iter(FID)
    count = 0
    for glist in gridList:
        Cur_FID = i.next()
        Cur_GC = glist[0]
        glist.sort()
        lr_Value = glist[-1]
        if lr_Value < 6:
            tie_LR = glist.count(lr_Value)
            if tie_LR >= 4 and lr_Value > Cur_GC:
                FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID] = lr_Value
                #print "The updated gridcode for FID ", Cur_FID, "is ", FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID]
                count += 1
    end_sim = count
    print end_sim
```

Thanks for any help....again!  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the code so that the simulations stop after the number of cells changed is less than 0.0001 of total cells.  I put the while loop in the wrong place.  If anyone is interested, here's the revised code for land use cellular automata.

```
import sys, string, csv

#Creating a dictionary of FID: LU_Codes from external txt file
text_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\FID_Whole_Copy.txt", "rb")
#Lines = text_file.readlines()
FID_GC_dict =  dict()
reader = csv.reader(text_file, delimiter='\t')
for line in reader:
    FID_GC_dict[line[0]] = int(line[1])
text_file.close()

#Importing neighbor list file for each FID value
Neighbors_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\Pro_NL_Copy.txt","rb")
Entries = Neighbors_file.readlines()
Neighbors_file.close()
Neighbors_List = map(string.split, Entries)
#print Neighbors_List

#creates a list of the current FID
FID = [x[0] for x in Neighbors_List]
#print FID

#Calculate when to end the simulations (neglible change in land use)
tot_cells = len(FID)
end_sim = tot_cells
p = 0.0001

#Performs cellular automata rules on land use grid codes
while (end_sim > tot_cells*p):
    gridList = []
    for nlist in Neighbors_List:
        row = []
        for item in nlist:
            row.append(FID_GC_dict[item])
        gridList.append(row)
    #print gridList

    i = iter(FID)
    count = 0
    for glist in gridList:
        Cur_FID = i.next()
        Cur_GC = glist[0]
        glist.sort()
        lr_Value = glist[-1]
        if lr_Value < 6:
            tie_LR = glist.count(lr_Value)
            if tie_LR >= 4 and lr_Value > Cur_GC:
                FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID] = lr_Value
                print "The updated gridcode for FID ", Cur_FID, "is ", FID_GC_dict[Cur_FID]
                count += 1
    end_sim = count            
    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of cellular automata that you are programming so mine it's just a guess but usually cellular automata works by updating a whole phase ignoring updated values until the phase is finished.

When I had unexpected results for simple cellular automata it was because I just forgot to apply the phase to a backup grid, but I was applying it directly to the grid I was working on.

What I mean is that you should have 2 grids, let's call them `grid1` and `grid2`, and do something like

```
init grid1 with data
while number of generations < total generations needed
  calculate grid2 as the next generation of grid1
  grid1 = grid2 (you replace the real grid with the buffer)
```

Altering values of grid1 directly will lead to different results because you will mostly change neighbours of a cell that still has to be updated before having finished the current phase..

Comment: Ok, thank you.  That makes sense.  I will try to make that work with my code.  I believe I would just make a copy of the dictionary after the for loop and somehow relate that back to the initial dictionary.  Thanks again for your help.